# Executor service shutdown is not supported

Tags: java, websphere, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am using the executor service provided by IBM Websphere 8.5.5

```
ExecutorService es = (ExecutorService ) new InitialContext().lookup("wm/default")
```

when I call `es.shutdown()`method, I get the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ASYN0093E: The operation shutdown is not supported.
```

Why Websphere does not support the shutdown method? Should not I call that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server rejects the `shutdown` method in order to comply with the following requirement of the *Concurrency Utilities for Java EE Specification,  Section 3.1.6: Lifecycle* , which states:

> The lifecycle of ManagedExecutorService instances are centrally managed by the application server and cannot be changed by an application.

And more explicitly, *Section 3.1.6.1 Java EE Product Provider Requirements* , which explicitly states:

> The lifecycle of a ManagedExecutorService is managed by an application server. All lifecycle operations on the ManagedExecutorService interface will throw a java.lang.IllegalStateException exception. This includes the following methods that are defined in the java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService interface: awaitTermination(), isShutdown(), isTerminated(), shutdown(), and shutdownNow().

It seems likely this requirement exists to prevent applications from interfering with each other when both use the same executor.